# tomcat 7 manager app access denied

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

When I first go to the manager app `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`, there was a browser prompt login window asking for username and password. By entering the wrong username and password, the page returned 403(access denied).

So I googled a bit and setup as follows:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<user username="admin" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
<!-- these 2 lines was there before my editing -->
<user password="tom" roles="manager-script,admin" username="tom"/>
<user password="tomcat" roles="manager-script,admin" username="tomcat"/>
```

After restarting tomcat, the manager app this time shows 403 page directly without asking for username and password.
So I'm a bit confused. What kind of authentication is this manager app using?
And how can I login to the manager app?

Comment: I think you need the role "manager"

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with the browser and its policy to preserve active logins. For Firefox you can go to ''Tools'' -> ''Clear Recent History...'' and clear ''Active Logins''. Refreshing your manager app after that will pop up the prompt you were asking for.

Cheers,
β

Comment: This worked for me, and on Google Chrome, opening an incognito window did the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but this happend to me now and i struggled until i found the problem.
As described in the question, i had the tomcat-users.xml correctly configured, but the credentials were never asked by the browser.

In a new installation of Tomcat 7, the manager/META-INF/context.xml contains a filter to allow only localhost.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

After adding the network IP it worked.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|192\.168\.0\.\d+" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

In previous versions this Valve were commented.

Answer (score -1):

By default Tomcat 7 uses

> LockOutRealm

: This means the username is locked out after 5 failed log ins.

### SOLUTION

Add another user to tomcat-users.xml.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I suggest keep the XML file clean, like the above example.
Hope it helps.

Comment: (a) He already has a user with role 'manager-gui'; (b) adding another one isn't a solution to a lockout; and (c) there is no evidence of a lockout in the question. -1