# Tomcat7 manager app shows 403 access denied without prompting for credentials

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to access the manager app in tomcat7. However it doesnot even ask for credentials and shows 403 access denied directly. I have already set my conf/tomcat-users.xml file. Here is a snapshot :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="role1"/>
    <role rolename="manager"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manger-script"/>
    <user password="user1" roles="admin-gui" username="user1"/>
    <user password="user1" roles="manager-gui" username="user1"/>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat" username="tomcat"/>
    <user password="user1" roles="manager" username="user1"/>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1" username="both"/>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="role1" username="role1"/>
    <user password="user1" roles="manager-script,admin,tomcat" username="user1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

It was working fine for me a few days ago, though! Also, this is not a duplicate of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470179/tomcat-7-manager-app-access-denied) or any other as I am not even getting a prompt for credentials.